# How to append a list of csr matrices

Tags: python, scipy

I have a list of [csr matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) in a list called `L`. All the matrices have the same dimension which is `1` by `100000`. How can I append them so I end up with one csr matrix of dimension `len(L)` by `100000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a *vertical stack* i.e. [`vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html) will do:

```
from scipy.sparse import vstack

new_array = vstack(L).toarray()
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that `sparse.vstack` is basically a call to `sparse.bmat`.  That in turn collects all the `coo` style attributes of the matrices, and makes a new `coo` matrix from the joined arrays.  And then there's a final conversion back to your preferred format.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh!  That sounds potentially slow.

Comment: How are you building the `csr` matrices?  Assembling the whole `coo` style inputs yourself might be faster, but the `bmat` approach might be more convenient.

Comment: @hpaulj Sadly  the csr matrices are a product of another function but you are right I should rewrite the code so that it makes the whole matrix in one go.